# Accidental null character causes static variables to reset in C

Tags: c

I'm learning about static variables and would like to understand why a
mistake I made caused the behaviour that it did.

I have a function which returns a string:

```
char *hhmmss(int sec) {
    static char s[9];
    // hr, min, sec calcs
    sprintf(s, "%02d:%02d:%02d%c", hr, min, sec, '\0');  // intentional mistake
    return s;
}
```

As you can see, I initially thought I had to add the null character when
using sprintf.

The program has other functions, two of which also use static variables.

Now here's where it gets weird - my program worked as I expected until I
simply moved the function from the end of the program to before the function 
which calls it.  I made no other changes.  The two functions which use the
static variables now reset the static variables every time they are called,
instead of keeping their values for the run of the program.

It took me a long time to figure out it was the accidental addition of the
null character that was causing this.  Can someone explain what is actually
going on here?

Comment: You have two characters for `hr`, two for `min`, two for `sec`, two for the separators in between and two for the two null terminators. That's 10 characters. I guess the second null terminator isn't causing any problems on its own, but it's not fitting inside your array anymore, resulting in undefined behavior. That may be responsible for any issues the code has. What happens if you chance `s[9]` to `s[10]`?

Comment: Are you sure that more than 1 other variable is affected? While "undefined" basically means everything can happen, technically I would really be surprised if more than 1 byte of another variable was affected.

Comment: @Gerhardh The two static variables which I noticed were affected are used together in a third function, so it's likely the 1 broken variable caused the other to break.  I will test further to confirm this.

Comment: Unless you are developing for a RAM-restricted embedded system, you should bang your head on the keyboard, in a violent and damaging manner, every time you declare a char array smaller than [128].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're writing past the end of the array.

`s` contains 9 characters.  Your format string will write a total of 10 bytes: 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, an explicit 0 byte, and an implicit 0 byte.  So you write off the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This manifested in your program appearing to work before moving the variable, and an unrelated variable being changes after you moved it.

The problem can be fixed by either making `s` large enough to hold the extra character, or by removing the extra character from your format string which isn't needed.

Comment: And also obsolete `sprintf` should be replaced with `snprintf`.

Comment: @dbush I'm beginning to appreciate why it's called "undefined" behaviour.  This is the first time I've seen it in action.

Answer (score 2):

The `sprintf` call writes a total of 10 characters to the memory starting at `&s[0]`, which only has space for 9. This is Undefined Behavior, meaning anything at all might happen.

In practice, it's likely some other variable with static storage duration comes immediately after the storage for `s`, and that value is being overwritten.  Or possibly it's some of the data used internally by the program to keep track of whether a function-local `static` variable has already been initialized or needs its first-time initialization.  The order of your C code can change how the compiler decides to place this data within the program, which is likely why changing that order gave you those different results.

Answer (score 2):

Overflow by one error: the "%02d:%02d:%02d%c" does indeed format 9 characters, providing each %d value doesn't overflow.The problem comes when sprintf() adds its own \0 making a total of 10 characters.

This extra \0 overflows s[9] and wacks whatever follows it. Such "slight overflows" result in undefined behavior... it depends on what the compiler put after the array, which depends on where the variables are in memory. Everything from not being noticed to segment faults can occur.

Overflows of static memory, with the longest lifespan, are more likely to be noticed. It depends on something referencing the corrupted memory with a byte that has become zero. If this is the first character of another string then the overwritten string becomes zero-length.

Comment: _"which depends on where the variables are in the stack"_: he is overflowing a static variable which is not on the stack. The rest of the answer is OK.

Comment: Expanded my answer a bit in response to Jabberwocky's comment.